# SSAS Cube Processing Options - Disable Cube

Tags: ssas

I have a question around the options of cube processing. We have a cube which is part of the baseline product however we will require for development purposes HOWEVER wish to not process or deploy this particular cube. Is this possible in Visual Studio to configure this for a specific cube?

Comment: Could you just set security on this cube so nobody has access to it?

Comment: @jason: just noticed you've been a member for 4 years and haven't accepted any answers. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio you can't deploy cubes that are part of a multi-cube project individually: you deploy the whole SSAS project.

But you can set the deployed SSAS project's processing option to  "Do Not Process" and then deploy individual SQL Agent jobs (or C# if you prefer) to process specific cubes.